# Comparing two columns with variable ranges

Tags: excel

I have a reference Column in excel(suppose Col:A). the new data is entering in Column C. I want whenever a user enter data in Column C after leaving each cell in Column C the code check the value.

```
        Column A                   Column C
       ------------------------------------
          1001                     2000  
          2000                     1005
          1005                     2000
```

if the value is Column A the background changes to blue (here 1005 and 2000)

if the value is duplicate in Column C the background changes to red. (here 2000)

I know I can get a value in a cell exists in range like this

```
         =COUNTIF(A1:A140;C1)
```

but I don't want to repeat it for every cell , because neither the number of cell in column A is distinguish, nor in column C.

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. Please add some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select column C then use Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule. Once the **New Formatting Rule** dialog is open, choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following for the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box.

```
=countif($a:$a; $c1)
```

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select a blue *Fill*. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> once to accept the new format then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.

With all of column C still selected, repeat with `=countif($c$1:$c1; $c1)>1` and a red *Fill*.

Your results should resemble the following.

[image: Red Blue Conditional Formatting]

Comment: when I want to add =countif($a:$a,$C1) It gives the error : "we found a problem with this formula.Try clicking insert function on the formulas tab to fix it or click help...." and the insert function also is disabled

Comment: My apologies; I've just noticed that the formula you supplied in your question used semicolons, not commas as the list separator character. Replace the commas with semicolons as I've done above.